# What is C# equivalent of Java's ClassName.class.getSimpleName()

Tags: java, c#, class

I am trying to rewrite Java code to C# and I am facing the problem that C# has not got this Java method. Can you please give me the C#'s equivalent of this method or some other way to get the class name.

Comment: ``typeof(ClassName).Name``

Comment: in c# 6 more better ``nameof(ClassName)``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
typeof(ClassName).Name
```